# Localizing angularJS template on server side using RAZOR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am developing a SPA application using AngularJS and ASP.Net MVC webapi. There will be a bunch of view templates that would be served on request.

This application is required to be localized.

I was wondering how (and if) I can use RAZOR engine to pre-process the template file and insert localized text in place of placeholders before it is delivered to the client?

I have seen a few solutions that suggested delivering a localized message file and using angular's binding capability. I think using binding in this scenario is wasteful, because the text is not going to change ever (after getting delivered to the client).

Any suggestions?